# Nodejs test image resizing with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I've used `graphicmagick` to resize a image in my `nodejs` app.

The problem is when writing the unit tests, I cant seem to find any direction or examples on this. Does it make sense that I test the image resizing, seeing that I'm using a third-party module? If yes, how could I write a test for my code?

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var util = require('util');

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var _800px = {
    width: 800,
    destinationPath: "large"
};

var _500px = {
    width: 500,
    destinationPath: "medium"
};

var _200px = {
    width: 200,
    destinationPath: "small"
};

var _45px = {
    width: 45,
    destinationPath: "thumbnail"
};

var _sizesArray = [_800px, _500px, _200px, _45px];

var len = _sizesArray.length;

// handler for dev environment

exports.GruntHandler = function (filepath) {

    console.log("Path to file is: " + filepath);

    // get the file name
    var srcFile = filepath.split("/").pop();

    var dstnFile = "dst";

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcFile.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        console.error('unable to infer image type for key ' + srcFile);
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        console.log('skipping non-image ' + srcFile);
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i<len; i++) {

        // Transform the image buffer in memory.
        gm(filepath)
            .resize(_sizesArray[i].width)
            .write(dstnFile + "/" + _sizesArray[i].destinationPath + "/" + srcFile, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
    }


   console.log(" grunt handler called!");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention when writing unit tests, is to test only the isolated unit.
All external dependencies should be stubbed/mocked, so you can check only the logic in your unit (in this case your unit is your module).

As to *what* to test, your unit's only public method is "GruntHandler", so this is the only method you should test, as it is the service that this unit provides to other units.

In order to replace all the module's dependencies, I like to use the proxyquire package. It replaces "require" calls with stubs you can control.

I've written an example test using the testing stack that I use personally: proxyquire, mocha, sinon for spies, chai for assertions.

Setup - put this in a "test-helper" module to require in all test files:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
```

And in your test file:

```
require('./test-helper');
describe('Image Resizing module', function () {
  var gmSubclassStub = sinon.stub();

  var testedModule = proxyquire('path-to-tested-file', {
    'gm': {subClass: sinon.stub().returns(gmSubclassStub)}
  });

  describe.only('GruntHandler', function () {
    it("should call gm write with correct files", function () {
      // Arrange
      var filepath = 'pepo.jpg';

      // Spies are the methods you expect were actually called
      var write800Spy = sinon.spy();
      var write500Spy = sinon.spy();
      var write200Spy = sinon.spy();
      var write45Spy = sinon.spy();

      // This is a stub that will return the correct spy for each iteration of the for loop
      var resizeStub = sinon.stub();
      resizeStub.withArgs(800).returns({write:write800Spy});
      resizeStub.withArgs(500).returns({write:write500Spy});
      resizeStub.withArgs(200).returns({write:write200Spy});
      resizeStub.withArgs(45).returns({write:write45Spy});

      // Stub is used when you just want to simulate a returned value
      gmSubclassStub.withArgs(filepath).returns({resize:resizeStub});

      // Act - this calls the tested method
      testedModule.GruntHandler(filepath);

      // Assert
      expect(write800Spy).calledWith("dst/large/pepo.jpg");
      expect(write500Spy).calledWith("dst/medium/pepo.jpg");
      expect(write200Spy).calledWith("dst/small/pepo.jpg");
      expect(write45Spy).calledWith("dst/thumbnail/pepo.jpg");
    });
  });
});
```

More about sinon spies, stubs, and mocks: http://sinonjs.org/

Proxyquire: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

And a great tutorial about all this together: http://kroltech.com/2014/02/node-js-testing-with-mocha-chai-sinon-proxyquire/#.VPTS9fmUdV0

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However this does not work as expected. I get an assertion errror:
`AssertionError: expected Expected Anonymous mock([...]) once (never called) to have been called with arguments 45`

Comment: Try replacing `var filepath = 'some file path';` with `var filepath = 'file.jpg';`. The error means the expectation wasn't met. We're expecting resize to be called, but it's never called. I failed to notice the regex filtering of the file types, that's why the filepath 'some file path' is stopping the method from reaching the resize code. This is actually a test case you'll also want to check: "should not call resize when file type doesn't match"

Comment: If `'aws-sdk': {'s3'....` and `'util': utilStub` are not removed this triggers an error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`.
Having removed those two lines from the code I get the following error:
`TypeError: object is not a function` and this points to the line where we act: `testModule(filepath);`

Comment: If I call `testModule.GruntHandler(filepath)` to trigger the correct method this actually triggers the image resizing and resizes my target image.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer. Actually tested it this time :) Your code isn't using aws and util so I removed them. Also, it makes more sense to set the expectations on the gm "write" method, which is the actual output of the unit you're testing, and not the "resize" method, which is just a step in the process. Should work now!

Comment: I have another question closely connected to this one. Its actually the rest of the code, another module in the file which I thought I wouldnt need help on once I had seen how to test this module, but am having trouble with it as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881483/nodejs-testing-aws-with-mocha