# aws-sdk upload to S3 works in KOA but stops working when invoked via Mocha

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mocha.js, koa

I need to upload a file to s3 from koa, I'm pretty new to koa and probably missing something obvious. It actually does complete with 200, but the file never shows up on s3.

Here is a fragment from my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var jwt = require('koa-jwt');


var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
var koaBody = require('koa-body');

const app = module.exports = require('koa')()
  .use(koaBody({multipart:true})) // this is to pase only multipart forms
  .use(require('./routes/common'))
  .use(require('./routes/auth'))
  .use(require('./routes/users_public'))
  .use(jwt({ secret: SECRET }))
  //protected routes below this line
  .use(require('./routes/subcontractors_private'))

  .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

subcontractors_private.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');


var S3_BUCKET = require('../consts').S3_BUCKET;
var S3_OPTIONS = require('../consts').S3_OPTIONS;


module.exports = require('koa-router')()

.post('/subcontractors/:subcontractor_id/coi', function *(next) {
  var body = JSON.stringify(this.request.body, null, 2)

  let subcontractor_id = this.params.subcontractor_id;
  var file = this.request.body.files.coi.path;
  var body = fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(zlib.createGzip());


  var s3obj = new AWS.S3(
  {params:
    {
      Bucket: 'coi-test',
      Key: 'i/' + subcontractor_id + '.png.zgip'
    }
  });        

  s3obj.upload({Body: body})
    .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
      console.log(evt);
    })
    .send(function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
    });


  this.response.status = 200;
  this.body = { "result": "subcontractor CIO successfully uploaded"};
  })
  .routes();
```

And finally, fragments of the subcontractor_private.js from the test folder:

```
'use strict';

const supertest = require('co-supertest'); // SuperAgent-driven library for testing HTTP servers
const expect    = require('chai').expect;  // BDD/TDD assertion library
require('co-mocha');                     // enable support for generators in mocha tests using co
var uuid = require('uuid');

var db = require('../../consts').DB;
var moment = require('moment');

const app = require('../../app.js');

const request = supertest.agent(app.listen());

var assert = require('assert');

describe('/subcontractors private routes testing', function() {

  it.only('should be able to upload COI for subcontractor', function*() {

    const coi_expires_at = moment().add(1, 'd').format();
    const response =
      yield request.post('/subcontractors')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    .send({name: "Joe Doh"})
    .end();

    //now try to upload the coi file
    const response1 =
    yield request.post('/subcontractors/' + response.body.subcontractor.id + "/coi")
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
    .field('coi_expires_at', coi_expires_at)
    .attach('coi', './assets/logo-big.png')
    .end();

    expect(response1.status).to.equal(200, response1.text);
    expect(response1.body).to.be.an('object');
    expect(response1.body).to.be.json;
    expect(response1.body).to.contain.keys('result');
    expect(response1.body.result).to.equal('subcontractor CIO successfully uploaded');

  });
});
```

I tried the upload code as a standalone js file (ran via node) and it works fine. But when I run it as a node app from mocha test -- the method completes with response 200 and never finishes the upload. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no information on the web that I can find which explains how to do the longer running tasks like upload from the node and have node return correct response codes back to the browser after the task completes.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example showing how this is being invoked from koa/mocha?

Comment: good point -- updated the original post with more examples

Comment: thanks to @MK help it appears that the code only does not work under mocha. Arguably, one should not unit test uploads to s3 on life aws account. Any suggestions how to mock it up would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, so it appears that something in mocha breaks stuff deep inside aws-sdk.  I'm not immediately able to understand what and how, but it is clear the request is not actually happening.  This SO question might provide some tips on how to mock S3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881483/nodejs-testing-aws-with-mocha

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with asynchronous nature of this stuff.  The test finishes w/o waiting for the request to finish (or even start properly).
I am not entirely clear how to do it correctly, but adding this:

```
  it.only('should be able to upload COI for subcontractor', function*(done) {
```

(done callback argument) makes the test wait for the "done" callback to be invoked, thus allowing aws sdk to finish the request.  I am not sure how to fix your test, however, because the this is twice-asynchronous.  The controller method in your koa server returns asynchronously w/o waiting for S3 request to finish, so the mocha test has no way of waiting for S3 processing to complete.

(also see my related question:
[aws-sdk s3 upload not working from mocha test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337620/aws-sdk-s3-upload-not-working-from-mocha-test))

Comment: This is it, I was able to see the file uploaded from the test, and of course, my test failed with timeout because I do not call the done call back -- I will figure it out, but your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you much!

Comment: So, keep digging into this. The issue is that Promises and Callbacks should not be mixed with generators. KOA is a generator based framework, while aws-sdk is based on callbacks. I'm wondering if there is a decent generator wrapper available for aws-sdk -- so far I was not able to find one.