# aws-sdk s3 upload not working from mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, aws-sdk

Trying to run s3 upload from a mocha test:

```
'use strict';

describe('S3 test', function() {
    it.only('S3 test 1', function*() {
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        //AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
        var s3 = new AWS.S3({
            params: { Bucket: 'test-1-myBucket', Key: 'myKey' }
        });
        s3.createBucket(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error:", err);
            } else {
                s3.upload({
                    Body: 'Hello!'
                }, function() {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but nothing happens, it is not sending the http request at all.  Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh.  Its asynchronous so I need to use the done callback:

```
'use strict';

describe('S3 test', function() {
    it.only('S3 test 1', function(done) {
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        //AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
        var s3 = new AWS.S3({
            params: {
                Bucket: 'mkruk-myBucket',
                Key: 'myKey'
            }
        });
        s3.createBucket(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error:", err);
                done();
            } else {
                s3.upload({
                    Body: 'Hello!'
                }, function() {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
                    done();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

may be missing accessKeyId and secretAccessKey

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: ""
});
```

then

```
s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'test-1-myBucket', 
    Key: 'myKey'
    Body: 'Hello!',    
}
```

Comment: well, no.  I do have them in my environment and if I didn't, I'd expect to get an error.  But I don't get anything at all.  Same code works fine outside of mocha.